# I am unable to upload a .csv file in postgresql database because I don't know how to put date structure in sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, data-cleaning

I downloaded a csv file for practising where date format is of two types as shown in picture.
[the picture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zEbs.png)
I tried to change the format to yyyy-mm-dd in excel but it is not happening.
and also, I can't upload the file in database in my postgresql. I used the data type "date" but it says I need a different datestyle.

code I have used:

```
create table sample(
    region varchar,
    country varchar,
    item_type varchar,
    sales_channel varchar,
    order_priority varchar,
    order_date date,
    order_id bigint,
    ship_date date,
    unit_sold int,
    unit_price decimal,
    unit_cost decimal,
    total_revenue decimal,
    total_cost decimal,
    total_profit decimal);

copy sample from 'E:\postgresql\bin\5m Sales Records.csv'
delimiter ',' csv header;

ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "3/26/2016"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT:  COPY sample, line 2, column ship_date: "3/26/2016"
SQL state: 22008
```

any guidance will be helpful, thanks

Comment: Per the error message this is `DateStyle` issue. In `psql` do `show datestyle` and add the result to your question.  My guess is you will have `DMY` in the setting and so `3/26/2016` is failing as there is no month 26. Your options for `DateStyle` can be found here [Date/times](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html)  in `Table 8.15. Date Order Conventions`.

Comment: You have a larger issue than what changing 'DateStyle' can resolve. You have **inconsistent** strings representing dates; both *yyyy-mm-dd*  and *fmmm-dd-yyyy*. See [Table 9-26](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE) and following descriptions (the format specifications apply to to_date as well)Changing 'DataStyle' to satisfy one will cause the other to fail.

Comment: You should be able to correct this within Excel (perhaps take another try at that and perhaps individual cells), failing to do that your best bet might by load your data to a staging table with all columns defined as text, validate and correct in there, then load the corrected data into your actual table, applying the necessary conversions. You can then Truncate the staging table for the next cycle. then truncate the staging table for the next cycle.

Comment: @Belayer. Changing the `DateStyle` will not cause the other `ISO`(2021-07-11) format to fail, even if the string has a leading space. Try it yourself. So you can have inconsistent strings.

Comment: @Belayer This  inconsistent style is not really a problem here if datestyle is set correctly.  The NNNN-NN-NN format is always accepted and interpreted as YYYY-MM-DD, and NN/NN/NNNN format will be accepted and/or interpreted according to datestyle setting.

Comment: Cool! Good to know. Always avoided different formats, guess it comes from too much time in Oracle. Wonder if this also works there now. I'll have to give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I did that and it is ISO, DMY as you have guessed. How to add a new datestyle of mm/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: You don't want to make the `DateStyle` change permanent as they make conflict with existing code. What you can do is just before the `COPY`  is `SET DateStyle = 'sql, mdy';`. This will temporarily set `DateStyle` for the session only. If you want to continue in the session after the `COPY` with the default setting then do `SET DateStyle = default ;` For more on `SET` options see [SET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html).

Comment: i have found out that, the mm/dd/yyyy format is actually a text format, not date format in the csv file. any idea how to make it a date format ?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, but then what about the dd-mm-yyyy formatted dates on the csv file? will that be automatically fixed irrespective of the new datestyle ?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more information in your question. FYI, `mm/dd/yyyy` is a date formatted string so I'm not sure what you are referring to. How do you know there are `dd-mm-yyyy` dates in the file? Please add a portion of the CSV file as text that illustrates your issues to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver in excel the code "=istext(cell)" tells if a data is actual date or date formatted string. i have put a portion of the file in the question. the mm/dd/yyyy is not actually date.

Comment: Postgres does not care. If it is a properly formatted date string, which ' mm/dd/yyyy' is, Postgres will accept it.  Besides you don't the Excel raw date anyway, they are a mess. You want a date string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize comments into sort of an answer:

```
create table csv_test(id integer, date_fld date);

--CSV file(csv_test.csv
1, 2021-07-11
2, 7/11/2021
3, 7/14/2021

show datestyle ;
 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, MDY

 \copy csv_test from '/home/aklaver/csv_test.csv' with csv;
COPY 3


select * from csv_test ;
 id |  date_fld  
----+------------
  1 | 2021-07-11
  2 | 2021-07-11
  3 | 2021-07-14
(3 rows)

set datestyle = 'iso, dmy';
SET

\copy csv_test from '/home/aklaver/csv_test.csv' with csv;
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: " '7/14/2021'"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT:  COPY csv_test, line 3, column date_fld: " '7/14/2021'"
```

CSV values are text, so your date needs only to be in a correctly formatted date style. The second copy failed because the date style date order was 'dmy' and the value is `7/14/2021` and 14 is not a month number. This is why there is a date/month order setting, as `7/11/2021` could either be 'July 11 2021' or 'November 7 2021'. Postgres needs the user to tell it what ordering it is looking at.

Comment: thanks, I used the 'sql, mdy' instruction and then 'default' query for solving this issue. Is this a data wrangling method ?

Comment: Would you accept the answer, thank you. Data wrangling is an open ended definition, so yes it would qualify. Basically you adapted one system to accept data from another.

Comment: heyy, sorry for the delay, i did not know before that clicking on the tick accepts the answer lol, done it